# How to globally overwrite/overload python functions (os.path.walk)?

Tags: python

[scandir.walk() is a better alternative to os.walk()](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir).

I want to replace all instances of os.walk() with scandir.walk(). However, I also want to make sure all future devs will be using scandir.walk().

This will be hard to enforce, and so I am wondering if it is possible to override the default os.walk() functionality.

Comment: Do you mean replace it for just one machine? Or everybody everywhere? (hint: the second one is _wrong_)

Comment: Correction, future devs in my company :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Python 3.5+

[`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) is now `scandir.walk`. Citing [PEP 471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/):

> As part of this proposal, *os.walk()* will also be modified to use *scandir()* rather than *listdir()* and *os.path.isdir()*.

It is

> now implemented using *os.scandir()*, which speeds it up by 3-5
>   times on POSIX systems and by 7-20 times on Windows systems.
>   [...] The implementation of this proposal was written by Ben Hoyt (initial > version) and Tim Golden (who helped a lot with the C extension > module). It lives on GitHub at [benhoyt/scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir).

#### Older Python

Just patch it:

```
>>> import scandir
>>> import os
>>> os.walk
<function walk at 0x7f3c02afc8c0>
>>> scandir.walk
<function walk at 0x7f3c00fe28c0>
>>> os.walk = scandir.walk
>>> os.walk is scandir.walk
True
>>> os.walk('/')
<generator object walk at 0x7f3c02b53500>
```

because

> The API for *scandir.walk()* is exactly the same as *os.walk()*

(from the [GitHub page](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir#walk))

Answer (score 0):

If you really want permanence it may be worthwhile to actually modify `os.py` file in your Python installation.  To avoid a hassle if you ever want to revert,  I would recommend this sort of thing in that file:

```
def walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False):
    """walk function doc string"""


    import scandir
    return scandir.walk(top, topdown, onerror, followlinks)
```

I think this will work, but I'm not entirely sure and I'm too paranoid about messing up *my company's* python install to test it.  So you may have to do some playing around, but I think modifying the actual `os` module is what you want.  Hope this helps